# Using array to create date in SAS with only day and month

Tags: arrays, sas

I need to use the day and month variables to create a date variable using the array function. For example, let's say the year is 2022, which needs to be included in the date.

I tried the following codes, but it doesn't seem to work. SAS gave me a number but not sure that's the correct date. Thanks for your help.

```
array day{1} day_1;
array month{1} month_1;
array date{1} date_1;
do i=1 to dim(day);
date{i}=MDY(month{i},day{i},2022);
end;
format date_1 mmyydd10.;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your posted code does not have a DATA statement telling SAS what dataset you want to create. Nor anyway to find the existing DAY_1 or MONTH_1 variables.  If the variables are in an existing SAS dataset then add a SET statement.

If there is only one DAY variable and one MONTH variable there is no need for the ARRAY or the DO loop.

```
data want;
  set have;
  date_1=MDY(month_1,day_1,2022);
  format date_1 mmyydd10.;
run;
```

If you do have multiple variables then include them in the arrays and the FORMAT statement.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array day   day_1-day_3
  array month month_1-month_3;
  array date  date_1-date_3;
  do i=1 to dim(day);
    date{i}=MDY(month{i},day{i},2022);
  end;
  format date_1-date_3 mmyydd10.;
  drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for not pasting the set dataset procedures conducted above. I have three DAY variable and MONTH variable recorded at different time, so array makes sense?

Comment: Yes.  Your code was fine, just list all of the variables in the ARRAY statement. Don't forget to also list all of the new date variables in the FORMAT statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this does make sense in terms of coding. When I ran the codes, SAS didn't give me any erroring message, but the date1-date3 variables are showing five-digit numbers like 11236 and 11125 instead of date format (given I changed the year to 1990). Wondering if i missed anything here.

Comment: Make sure the variable names listed in the DATE array definition and the FORMAT statement match.

Comment: lol, I realized that it should be MMDDYY10., I accidentally put in the MMYYDD10. THANK you so much!!!

Comment: The avoid confusing 50% of your audience I recommend using DATE or YYMMDD format instead of MMDDYY or DDMMYY.

Comment: @Evan including your log when you say you're having issues would help with that.